# Reducing Size of Linux Kernel Image

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am working on ARM V7 architecture based Embedded Board with only 128 MB of flash memory and i want to fit Bootloader Image, Linux Kernel Image as well as root file system inside it, for this my primary target is to reduce the size of the boot loader and Linux Kernel image,

I have done the following optimizations for reducing kernel size,

```
     1. Deleted all the printk messages from displaying which reduced some memory,
     2. Turning off Sysfs Support decreased the size of the kernel substantially,
     3. Booting without procfs is one more work around i tried, but many pseudo 
        file systems require it.
```

I want to know all the possible techniques for optimization and reducing the size of the linux kernel.
I request to provide any references.

Comment: The last time I left out `sysfs` (a long time ago, back in 2.6.25), the Ethernet driver broke; there was an obscure dependency!  Reducing the kernel size can be a valid goal, but your reason seems misguided, i.e. the zImage compressed kernel image probably uses only a few percent of the flash.

Comment: @sawdust Next time you find that a driver breaks if you disable SYSFS, please file a bug report. It means the driver is buggy.

Answer (score 6):

Compared to 128 MB of flash, the size of your bootloader and kernel images should be comparatively quite small, and your root filesystem be the biggest part. So why do you focus on reducing the size of your bootloader and kernel, instead of looking at what is probably the biggest part: your root filesystem.

Comment: Not a real answer to an XY question, but an excellent comment.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should remove unneeded configs (network, security, unneeded drivers, ...).
"CC_OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE" should be enabled.

Enable kernel compression (for example: HAVE_KERNEL_BZIP2), ramdisk compression (for example: RD_BZIP2) and initramfs compression (INITRAMFS_COMPRESSION_BZIP2).

Comment: It's a pain but I would suggest also to disable modules support, and enable all and ONLY your hw required drivers, compiled statically with the kernel image. this should allow you to avoid having an initram disk to load modules/drivers at boot time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting your file system to either jffs2 or yffs if you have not already done so.